# Python prediction value output into excel

Tags: python, output, export-to-excel, prediction, forecasting

I create the following codes and get the forecast chart but don't know how to export the predicted value into excel.

```
import statsmodels as sm
sm.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing

model_expo1= sm.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing(monthly_series,trend='add',
                                                     seasonal='add',seasonal_periods=12)

results_1= model_expo1.fit()

results_1.summary()

fit1= model_expo1.fit().predict(0,len(monthly_series))

mae1= abs(monthly_series- fit1).mean()

forecast1=model_expo1.fit().predict(0,len(monthly_series)+12)
monthly_series.plot(label='actual')
forecast1.plot(label='forecast')
```

Thank you

Comment: save it to a pandas dataframe and then use `to_excel()`

Comment: Hi there, I am new to coding, do you mind helping me how to convert? please

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a DataFrame containing the forecast values.
forecast_df = pd.DataFrame({"forecast": forecast1})

# Write the DataFrame to an Excel file.
forecast_df.to_excel("forecast_values.xlsx")
```

Comment: Dear Gandhi, Do you mind guiding me on the best way to learn forecasting through ML and sales analysis in python, please?